# BigQuery view in a google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get result from BigQuery view in a google sheets. 
To do that I'm using a script from Ido Green that he posted on your blog. https://greenido.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/big-query-and-google-spreadsheet-intergration/
It works well for Tables, but I need to extend to query Views.
When I'm using SQL with View I get this error:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: Invalid table name: `my_project:Data_Set.1_0_View_all_users_with_domain_names` [Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)].
```

Comment: have you tried to follow suggestion in that error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify otherwise the BigQuery API will [default](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) to LegacySQL and you're using StandardSQL notation. You can try setting `useLegacySql` to false by replacing line 31 to something like:

```js
queryRequest.setQuery(sql).setTimeoutMs(100000).setUseLegacySql(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried your syntax and without .setTimeoutMs(100000)

Still getting new error:

TypeError: Cannot find function setUseLegacySQL in object {"query":"SELECT * FROM `my_project.Data_Set.1_0_View_all_users_with_domain_names` LIMIT 1000"}.

Comment: Sorry, edited, it should be `setUseLegacySql` instead of `setUseLegacySQL`